# How can I get the value before after a dot(.) in version name using Regex in ANT

Tags: regex, ant, version

I have a version number as `2018.1.2` and `2018.1`, I have a scenario like I want to the version name as `2018.1` even though the version is selected as `2018.1.2` or `2018.1` (The version name may differ) from the Jenkins build parameters.

I have tried the regex like below:

```
<propertyregex property="MyReleaseVersion"
                       input="2018.1.2"
                       regexp="(.*).(.*)"
                       select="\1"
                       casesensitive="false" />
```

But I am not properly getting the output as what I am expected. May I know how can I have a regex to get the output for my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

`\d+\.\d+ /g`

The version number is considered as everything before the second `.`. Hence, the regex matches digits before and after the first `.` including the dot itself.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zLfRy8/1)

Comment: What do you mean both versions? This regex is selecting `2018.1` for both the input strings (see demo link).

Comment: Ya sorry, got it with the demo. Is there a regex to take the value after the second dot alone ? If it is 2018.1.2, I need the 2 alone.

Comment: Use this `\d+\.\d+\.(\d)`. The first capturing group will then contain the desired number. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zLfRy8/2)